# OpenGL - Coloring a triangle

Tags: opengl-es

I can currently draw the triangle, set the background as Red, but I can't color the triangle. What obvious step am I missing here?

[Current Progress - Red background and black triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUQww.png)
[image]

```cpp
const GLfloat vertices[] = {
    vertex1_s, vertex1_t, 0,
    vertex2_s, vertex2_t, 0,
    vertex3_s, vertex3_t, 0
};

glClearColor(1,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

const GLfloat colors[] = {
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1
};
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
eglSwapBuffers(dpy, surface);
```

Comment: For some reason, no matter what color pointers i give in the colors[ ], the result is the same as shown in the link.

Comment: Is accidentally texturing or lighting enabled? (`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` or `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)`)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Not using any texture or anything.

Comment: It's off topic, but if you are learning OpenGL ES I would really recommend starting with OpenGL ES 2.0 or newer. OpenGL ES 1.1 is an evolutionary dead-end.

Comment: @solidpixel how do i know which version am i using ? How did you decipher that i have 1.1 ?

Comment: `glColorPointer()` is one of the legacy fixed function operations; it's doesn't exist in ES 2.0.